# Mobile site redirection and Google crawlers

Tags: mobile, googlebot, flash

I have a HTML website where users can select a product (going through categories/subcategories) and then when they choose the product they can customize it in a Flash application.

I would like to redirect users with no Flash Player to a mobile site (which is also HTML) where they will have a smaller range of categories and a non-Flash version of app:

```
var hasFlash = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));

if( !hasFlash ){
    document.location.href = '/mobile';
}
```

But I suppose this method will cause Google spiders/crawlers to omit the original HTML website and just index the mobile site (limited categories and less content).

Is there any way that I could redirect the users with no Flash to the mobile site, but make the Google crawlers to index the original site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't run your JavaScript, so you don't have to worry about this specific issue.  Also note that Google cannot always index content in SWF files.

In general, I would suggest having your no-Flash fallback content on the same page as the Flash content.

Comment: @user2555388, That is correct.  However, I wouldn't bank on this being true 5 years from now.

Comment: I cannot have the fallback/redirection on the page where the flash content is, it needs to be done before on the main index of the html website (far before they get to the flash site). But this I had no clue about: "Google doesn't run your JavaScript". So google crawlers will not get redirected?

Comment: Thank you for your help Brad. I can't upvote you , not enough rep :(